# show full table inside table cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

My goal is to have a table that will list food categories.

Under each category name is another table that will list various foods. This sub table should be fully expanded. I can get the data to display, it's just that the layout is giving me a headache.

So under each food category label in the parent table, there should be a fully expanded sub table of food items. However, when I run this, the subtable is collapsed all the way. Only the food category label is showing. I can see the food items if i start clicking and scrolling, but it's not fully expanded. Any help is appreciated!

My layout ultimately looks like the following
[image]

I have

```
class ParentFoodTable: UITableViewController
```

and each cell(which contains a label and another tableview) is configured

```
class ChildFoodCell: UITableViewCell,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate
```

Once again, I can get the data to display, it's just that the layout and appearance is atrocious in that the cell of the parent table is not expanding or conforming to the height of the sub table.

ParentFoodTable

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

ChildFoodCell

```
func setUpTable()
{
    subMenuTable?.delegate = self
    subMenuTable?.dataSource = self
    subMenuTable?.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    subMenuTable?.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0

}
```

Comment: Do you really want everything in one table? Why not make a new screen with each sub-table, the well known "Master-Detail" design. This way you can even have sub-sub-tables, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options, the first as suggested by Koen is to use the master/detail model with a second view controller showing the items in a selected category.

The second option is to use a "grouped tableview" where the groups correspond to your categories and then the items correspond to items within the category.

Basically, that would look something like:

```
class Category {
    let name : String
    let items : [Item]

    init(name:String, items:[Item]) {
        self.name = name
        self.items = items
    }
}

class Item {
    let name : String

    init(name:String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class MyTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    var data = [Category]()

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data[section].items.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return data[section].name
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let category = data[indexPath.section]
        let item = category.items[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. I was overcomplicating the situation